# Multiple index.html in Visual Studio web project

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, visual-studio-2015, single-page-application

With Web.Config, I can create one transform file per build configuration.
Can something similar be done with files of other types?
In my **Release** build configuration I want to reference my **minified** content files.

Is it possible to have different **index.html** files in a Visual Studio 2015 Web project based on build configuration?